# How Can a Owner Add a Function to Already Deployed Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, contract, nft

I'll be frank, I made a stupid mistake. In polygon network I deployed a NFT smart contract. I forgot to add withdraw function in my smart contract. Can we add this function to my smart contract that already deployed.

You can see the smart contract code in here:
https://polygonscan.com/address/0xeCd093eD38449d8d64bb015D97072BdcaA594832#code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

[Upgrading smart contracts is not possible on EVM chains unless the contracts were designed for it](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts). You can read more on the topic on Ethereum StackExchange.

[I also suggest you test you minimally unit tests contracts before deploying](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8593/620).